# Dropwizard 1.0.0-rc2 registerDefaultExceptionMappers unrecogized field

Tags: java, configuration, yaml, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard 1.0.0-rc2 and want to stop the default exception mappers from being registered.  All documentation suggests that adding

```
server:
    registerDefaultExceptionMappers: false
```

Will stop them being registered, but when I try to add them to the configuration file then I get a ConfigurationParsingException that server.registerDefaultExceptionMappers is an unrecognised field.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: application-config.yml has an error:
      * Unrecognized field at: server.registerDefaultExceptionMappers
        Did you mean?:
          - adminConnectors
          - applicationConnectors
          - requestLog
          - idleThreadTimeout
          - adminContextPath
            [19 more]

        Caused by:
        io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: application-config.yml has an error:
          * Unrecognized field at: server.registerDefaultExceptionMappers
            Did you mean?:
              - adminConnectors
              - applicationConnectors
              - requestLog
              - idleThreadTimeout
              - adminContextPath
                [19 more]

            Caused by:
            com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "registerDefaultExceptionMappers" (class io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory), not marked as ignorable (24 known properties: "umask", "gid", "idleThreadTimeout", "applicationContextPath", "adminContextPath", "adminMinThreads", "rootPath", "allowedMethods", "user", "uid", "nofileHardLimit", "adminMaxThreads", "adminConnectors", "applicationConnectors", "minThreads", "gzip", "maxQueuedRequests", "serverPush", "group", "shutdownGracePeriod", "maxThreads", "nofileSoftLimit", "startsAsRoot", "requestLog"])
             at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.company.manager.ApplicationConfiguration["server"]->io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory["registerDefaultExceptionMappers"])
```

How am I supposed to specify this, or is it a bug in 1.0.0-rc2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a little test project to see if this is broken and it works just fine for me. I am using DW 1.0.0-rc2.

My Starter Class:

```
public class Starter extends Application<Configuration> {

    @Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        environment.jersey().register(HelloWorldResource.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Starter().run("server", "/Users/artur/dev/repo/dw-test/src/main/resources/configuration.yaml");
    }

}
```

My resource:

```
    @Path("/hello/world")
    public class HelloWorldResource {

        @GET
        public String get() {
            return "hello";
        }

    }
```

My Configuration:

```
server:
    registerDefaultExceptionMappers: false
    applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 9085
```

This starts up just fine. I debugged the DefaultServerFactory and it works as expected.

I am not sure why this isn't working for you, but I would suggest to start and reproduce the problem as minimalistic as possible and then update your question with runable code to test against.

You might have broken it yourself by:

- Changing the AbstractServerFactory
- Using a custom ServerFactory that doesn't use this flag
- typo somewhere
- Configuration file being invalid

The field you are trying to set is in the subclass. Maybe you accidentally re-configured a different ObjectMapper that ignores subclass types?

At this point I would just be guessing, so I am going to wait on some feedback. However, to answer your question, the above is how it works, and there seems to be no bug :)

I hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: Appears that my ObjectMapper was stopping this.  Thanks